# How does looping through a list based on findElements work?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

First one in list is easy since you can use find Element.  I find the element and need to get information from preceding and following divs.  For the "n" element in the list, what is the xPath syntax for moving/backwards to other associated divs?

I have tried various x path following syntax such as:

```
following-sibling::div 
/following-sibling::div 
./following-sibling::div
```

And many others.  I just have not found the documentation for the correct syntax.

Comment: You might need to post the HTML that you are working with to help us answer this question. It's hard to visualize this issue without an HTML reference.The code sample you are using to iterate the elements would help too.

Answer (score 0):

**Preceding**:

Select all nodes that come before the current node as shown in the below screen.

**Following-sibling**:

Select the following siblings of the context node. Siblings are at the same level of the current node as shown in the below screen. It will find the element after the current node.

[Here](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html#15) you can find the correct syntax with examples.

You can also use `drive.findElements();` method in order to find similar elements. It will return you the collection of elements which you can iterate to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is entirely dependent on what HTML is displayed on the page you are trying to automate.

Without that context, I can only provide a generic answer, but here's how I would loop through a list of elements and grab information from preceding / following `div`'s:

```
// locate the elements you want to iterate
List<WebElement> elements_to_iterate = driver.findElements(By.xpath(someLocatorHere))

// iterate the elements in a foreach loop
for (WebElement element : elements_to_iterate) {

    // get preceding sibling
    WebElement preceding_element = element.find_element_by_xpath("./preceding-sibling::div")
    print(preceding_element.getText())

    // get following sibling
    WebElement following_element = element.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::div")
    print(following_element.getText())
}
```

As I mentioned, this is just a generic solution to give you an idea of how this would work. If you want some assistance with the locator strategy, posting your HTML would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find multiple elements then please find below example for your reference. Based on your site you need to implement same kind of logic.

[image]

Please refer above screenshot where I am trying to get label of two highlighted button from google

```
      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com"); // URL in the browser
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); // Maximize the browser

        String expectedTooltip="Search";

       List<WebElement> Listelements  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='FPdoLc VlcLAe']//input"));


        for (WebElement element: Listelements)
        {
            System.out.println("Element Text::"+element.getAttribute("aria-label"));
        }

        driver.close();
    }
```

**output:**

```
Element Text::Google Search
Element Text::I'm Feeling Lucky
```

Answer (score 0):

since the first one is easy; each elementList has a current-time and at least one picture

for (i=1; i < elementList.size(); i++) {
    WebElement nextInList = elmentList(i);
    WebElement getTime = nextInList.findElement(By.xpath("following::div[contains(@class, 'current-time')]"));
.
.
.
   WebElement picture = nextInList.findElement(By.xpath("preceding::a[1]"));
.
}